# How create routes in AngularJS + JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm creating a website and I'm using JavaScript + AngularJS, presently I create the routes for the application, but it always returns 404 not found on the server, I've tried several examples of the internet but none of them worked, here's an example of my code, remembering that The html pages are inside the WebContent:

```
<html ng-app="angularRoutingApp">
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="/index">index</a> <br> <a href="/">home</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.3/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script>
    var angularRoutingApp = angular.module('angularRoutingApp', ['ngRoute']);

    angularRoutingApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $routeProvider
            .when("/index", {
                template: "/index.html"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home.html'
            });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the `<ng-view>` element?

Comment: Actually the ng-view tag was not defined, but now I wrote it but still giving 404 not found, above is the change

Comment: I would suggest following a tutorial instead of trying random code you (apparently) copied and pasted off the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot the ng-view directive.

also,

- the href need to be with a hash prefix - or using the Link directive.
- the redirectTo key need to provide a view [name/address] & not a
  template
- if you want to use template files & not inline code use the templateUrl key

you can see an example of your code here: http://codepen.io/AceDesigns/pen/ZLXLKa

```
<html ng-app="angularRoutingApp">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <a href="#/index">index</a><br>
      <a href="#/">home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.3/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script>
      var angularRoutingApp = angular.module('angularRoutingApp', ['ngRoute']);
      angularRoutingApp.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
          .when("/index", {template:"<div>INDEX VIEW</div>"})
          .when("/home", {template:"<div>HOME VIEW</div>"})
        .when("/tempFile", {templateUrl: "views/temp_file.html"})
          .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```